# C++: Share variables with Multiple files

Tags: c++, c++11, global-variables, c++14, global

I'm trying to share global variables within multiple `.cpp` files. I had used `extern` keyword, but it doesn't meet what I want.

At the first, I have had four files as:

***** common.hpp *****

```
#ifndef COMMON_HPP
#define COMMON_HPP
#include <iostream>
void printVar();
void printVarfromA();
void setVar(char *str);
#endif
```

***** Base.cpp *****

```
#include "common.hpp"
extern char *var;
void printVar(){
    std::cout << var << std::endl;
}
void setVar(char *str){
    var = str;
}
```

***** A.cpp *****

```
#include "common.hpp"
char *var = (char*)"This is var from A";
void printVarfromA(){
    printVar();
}
```

***** main.cpp *****

```
#include "common.hpp"
int main(){
    printVarfromA();
    setVar((char*)"Var was Changed.");
    printVarfromA();
    return 0;
}
```

All thing goes fine, and the result was:

```
This is var from A
Var was Changed.
```

as I expected.

The problem arose when I have added a new file that shares the `var` variable, let's say `B.cpp`, where it contains a single line now:

***** B.cpp *****

```
char *var;
```

At this moment `ld returned 1 exit status` ***ERROR*** appeared.

I have tried several methods and searched a lot, but I couldn't get any solution.

**My question. *How to share variable within multiple files in C++?***

Comment: There can only be a *single definition* of global symbols in a program. Please read about the [One Definition Rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/One_Definition_Rule).

Comment: As for a possible solutions, is the `var` variable in `B.cpp` supposed to be used by the other [*translation unit*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Translation_unit_(programming))? Then you have to rename it. Otherwise, if it's supposed to be used *only* in `B.cpp` then you can put it in an anonymous namespace, or make it `static`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To share same variable in multiple units, you can use `extern` variable in units except the main one.

```
// In file a.cpp
#include "A.hpp"
extern int global_x;
void AsetX()
{
    global_x = 12;
}
// In file b.cpp
#include "b.HPP"
extern int global_x;
void BsetX()
{
    global_x = 10;
}
```

In main unit, declare the real variable there.

```
#include "A.hpp"
#include "b.HPP"
int global_x;
int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    std::cout << global_x << std::endl;
    AsetX();
    std::cout << global_x << std::endl;
    BsetX();
    std::cout << global_x << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Output will be

```
0
10
12
```

Hope that can help you.